# How to overwrite a record with same primary key in SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I am using Python to push data to SQL Server. Suppose I have a table like below:

[image]

I am pushing the data using following code and query

```
query = """INSERT INTO TestTable (Key, One, Two) values(?,?,?)"""
```

Next, I want to push a Data with values 'A2', 'A3' in column 'Two' and two new rows like below:

[image]

I want to have a query with inserts new row if the primary key is not present and overwrite the row when the primary key is present. I tried using `REPLACE INTO` instead of `INSERT INTO` but that does not seem to work in SQL Server.

Please can you help.

Comment: I think what you're talking about is what's often referred to as an "upsert" (update if exists, otherwise insert). You can read about some approaches here: https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2):

Sql Server supports the [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) statement for upserts.

And to upsert 1 tupple, `VALUES` can be used.

```
MERGE TestTable AS t
USING (VALUES (?,?,?)) AS s([Key], One, Two) 
ON (s.[Key] = t.[Key])
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
  INSERT ([Key], One, Two) 
  VALUES (s.[Key], s.One, s.Two) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  One = s.One,
  Two = s.Two;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e337ba28bf807d6c876e5c80a5695fa6)*

Comment: That worked well..awesome..

Comment: How would the query be if there was one more column say 'Three'? And primary key was a combination (composite key) of column 'Key' and 'Three'.

Comment: With a composite PK? Then change the `ON` clause, and the `INSERT`.   *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a0b8e9f5897564f782f5e331c852a1f3)*